# On Demand Singletons. Curious to know if this is a bad practise, and what a better way of achving my goal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When making pages in ASP.Net Core, I often need to do a bunch of work that only needs to happen ones during startup, such as loading a JSON file from disc, which will contain some data, typically just by a single RazorPage.

To achieve this typically do the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(SingletonThatLoadsStaticDataFromAJSONFile));
    // ...
}
```

**SingletonThatLoadsStaticDataFromAJSONFile.cs**

```
public class SingletonThatLoadsStaticDataFromAJSONFile
{
    public SomeData SomeData;

    public SingletonThatLoadsStaticDataFromAJSONFile(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "PathToJSONFile");
        this.SomeData = Deserialize(path);
    }
}
```

---

---

To make my life a bit easier, I've made an attribute so I can do this more effortlessly. That way I don't need to constantly add do services.AddSingleton(typeof(x)), and I can delete my RazorPages effortlessly folder without getting compiler errors.

**SingletonAttribute.cs**

```
public class SingletonAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    var singletonTypes = typeof(Program).Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<SingletonAttribute>().Any());

    foreach (var type in singletonTypes)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(type);
    }
    // ...
}
```

So I'm wondering what you guys do in these sort of situations, whether there is a better way of doing this.

Footnote: I'm not making a big scale-able website, so I don't care much about best practices in terms of using interfaces and scale-ability.

Comment: I've used a similar approach before. It is fine.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question ... but I've used [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) recently to clean up my assembly scanning for services code.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is okay. I would improve the wording.

Due to the overlap in wording, I would not name your attribute `Singleton`. It does not say what it actually does and worst case is misunderstood as implementing the Singleton (anti-)pattern.

Why not name it `AutomaticallyAddedToServicesAsSingletonAttribute` so you can annotate your class like this:

```
[AutomaticallyAddedToServicesAsSingleton]
public class FoobarReferenceDataReader
{
    //...
}
```

Now it's crystal clear what this does.